# How to get monday of the week which overlaps 2 months using moment js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, momentjs

I need to create few records on Mondays using an api.

And the rule to get the Monday is that it should be either first Monday of a given month or last Monday of the given month.

For example:

If the input date range is 1 Sep 2020 - 30 Sep 2020, I need to pull 28 Sep 2020.

If the input date range is 1 Oct 2020 - 31 Oct 2020, I need to pull 26 Oct 2020.

If the input date range is 1 Nov 2020 - 30 Nov 2020, I need to pull 30 Nov 2020.

If the input date range is 1 Nov 2020 - 31 Dec 2020, I need to pull 28 Dec 2020.

What I did so far is I pulled all the Mondays of given month and stored them in an array. I tried pulling 1st or last Monday of the month, but this works for few months and not for few others.

Hence, I was thinking if I get to know the week of a given day(Monday), which overlaps 2 months, then I can pull that Monday.

So my question is how to get Monday of the week which overlaps 2 months? I am using moment js.

Comment: How do you know if you need to get the first or the last Monday of any given month?

Comment: I need not know about that. If I get the week, which overlaps 2 subsequent months, that will take care of the right Monday. Ideally, the record should be created only once in month at the start of the month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe too late, but it could be helpful for future viewers.

The function takes `start` and `end`, but we only use `end`, so you can get rid of `start` as all the operations will be on `end` date in order to get the last monday. To achieve our goal we need to do two simple steps:

1. Get the end of the month with the `end` date.
2. Get the monday of the previous "calculated" date.

For the first step, we use [End of Time](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/end-of/) in order to get the end of the month (the last day).

> Mutates the original moment by setting it to the end of a unit of time.

Then we can get the Monday of the week the date is, and we can use [Date of Week](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/day/) with the date of previous step.

> Gets or sets the day of the week. [...] As of 2.1.0, a day name is also supported. This is parsed in the moment's current locale.

And taking your examples, we can test our function:

```js
function lastMonday(start, end) {
  console.log('Start is ', moment(start).format('LL'));
  console.log('End is ', moment(end).format('LL'));
  return moment(end).endOf('month').day('Monday');
}

console.log('Last monday is', lastMonday('2020-09-01', '2020-09-30').format('LL'));
console.log('Last monday is', lastMonday('2020-10-01', '2020-10-31').format('LL'));
console.log('Last monday is', lastMonday('2020-11-01', '2020-11-30').format('LL'));
console.log('Last monday is', lastMonday('2020-11-01', '2020-12-31').format('LL'));
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: Never too late :). Exactly what I wanted. All this while, I had been looping. Though it does the job, it isn't clean enough like this one. Thank you.